# Shifted Schwefel function implementation using Scala functional style

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Mathematical form of Shifted Schwefel function is described as follows.

[image]

I have implemented this function in scala using loops. Here is my code

```
def ShiftedSchwefel (   li  : List[Double]  ) : Double  =  {
 var res = 0.0
 for (i <- li.indices ) {
  var temp = 0.0
  for (j <- 0 to i) {
    temp += li(i)
  }
  res += pow    (  temp   ,   2  )
 }
 res
}
```

How can I rewrite this code using functional power of Scala in optimized way?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I updated question and added Shifted Schwefel function mathematical for.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly.
This should do what you want:

```
def ShiftedSchwefelRecursive[N : Numeric](data: List[N]): N = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._

  val zero = Numeric[N].zero
  val one = Numeric[N].one

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[N], acc: N, idx: N): N =
    remaining match {
      case n :: tail =>
        val sum = n * idx
        loop(
          remaining = tail,
          acc + (sum * sum),
          idx + one
        )

      case Nil =>
        acc
    }

  loop(remaining = data, acc = zero, idx = one)
}
```

Or you can just use higher-order functions to express this algorithm more concisely.

```
def ShiftedSchwefelHOF[N : Numeric](data: List[N]): N = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._

  data
    .iterator
    .zipWithIndex
    .map {
      case (n, idx) =>
        n * Numeric[N].fromInt(idx + 1)
    }.map { x =>
      x * x
    }.sum
}
```

Comment: your version of code is not working as needed. I updated your recursive  version of code and now it will be working as needed.

Comment: @user12140540 your edit is exactly my old code, which doesn't produce the correct answer. I updated my code when you showed the mathematical definition of the function. This one produces exactly the same output of your code.